# How can I reach to array data

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have some code which I am filing by some thing for bootstrap calendar. I try many ways how to get data from that array, but nothing work.

Here is what I get when I try to show array:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIIva.jpg

```
dataV[0]
dataV.lenght
```

it return nothing

I get data like this:

```
var dataV=[];
                $.post("getVacationData.php",
                {
                    name: "name",
                    city: "city"
                },
                function(data){
                    dataV[0] =data;
                });
```

Data in php:

```php
echo("{
        id: 0,
        name: 'Google I/O',
        state: 'reserved',
        startDate: new Date(2019, 4, 28),
        endDate: new Date(2019, 4, 29)
    }");
```

I do not know how to get it from array for dataSource which mast looks like

```
[{
        id: 0,
        name: 'Google I/O',
        state: 'reserved',
        startDate: new Date(2019, 4, 28),
        endDate: new Date(2019, 4, 29)
    }]
```

Comment: Not sure I understand the question, but if getVacationData.php returns an array of objects, then you would probably parse and assign that to `dataV`, not `dataV[0]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All data, regardless of type on the server, will be passed over the network as a string. You have to `JSON.parse` your data, since you are expecting JSON, when you receive it on the frontend. Like this:

```
var dataV=[];
$.post("getVacationData.php",
  {
      name: "name",
      city: "city"
  },
  function(data){
      dataV[0] = JSON.parse(data);
  });
```